# Importing Google-Play-Services in the android project removes R file

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-maps-v2, google-play-services

While trying to use google maps v2 for application as suggested by [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api/) i went about the procedure to get the key and then followed the [procedure](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)  for importing google play service.But when i import the library in my project i find R file is missing. Can anyone suggest how this error can be solved.

**EDIT**

Code and the log cat for it.

```
public class Maptest extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);
    }
}
```

XML FIle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

and then the permission given in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<permission
      android:name="com.curioussolutions.autoistdiary.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.curioussolutions.autoistdiary.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

  <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
```

`02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:271)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at com.curioussolutions.autoistdiary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 10:30:17.500: W/jdwp(21076): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
02-20 10:30:17.500: I/dalvikvm(21076): GC lifetime allocation: 2194 bytes`

Comment: It has something to do with your manifest file try scanning your manifest for broken tags and wrong attributes.

Comment: @hardcoded i have posted my snipet of my manifest file can you check it and let me know if i am missing something

Comment: By the way, did you run your application and got this logcat stack trace? If so then your R class now works fine?

Comment: check the logcat that i have posted now the R file error is not there rather gives me `ClassNotFoundException` and the class which its giving error is  `com.google.android.gms.R$styleable`

Comment: @sankettt: Have you got any solution..??

Answer (score 0):

Restart your project, run a clean and rebuild your project. If the problem remains try to check if there are other errors in other files. Try to edit and save de AndroidManifest.xml if the problem still remains.

Comment: Just edit some line, save, and rollback after that. When you save the manifest, the project will rebuild. I've suggested that because for me worked one of the times that I have your error.

Comment: probably you need to change the project property and project must be using google api target. e.g. API 10 Google Inc.

Comment: Right Click on the project-->Click on properties-->Click on android-->Select Google api 2.3.3 API 10. i hope this must solve your problem.

Comment: did you try with other google api's like with lower one ? Api 10?

Comment: I tried everything as @AnujSharma  said...but still the problem persists. When working with other project it works perfect and it gets imported

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be this one.

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source) 02-20 10:30:16.093: E/AndroidRuntime(21076): 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:271)
```

Because I think you have used.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

It should be.

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

The Google play services library uses SupportMapFragment not the MapFragment. You can also see it in their google map demo that they have used the SupportMapFragment.

Comment: Not working dude.. Please provide a feasible solution.. When I import google-play-service-lib. R.java file gets deleted..

Comment: @Mitesh do you have same problem with this one? Check your manifest most likely you made a mistake on tags in manifest. Did you posted your problem? If you have you can reply it here and I will look into it.

Comment: @Arman:: Thanks for replying.. Please check my problem.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677327/android-deletes-r-java-file-when-importing-google-play-services-lib