# Android - Deletes R.java file when importing google-play-services-lib

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am working on a project in which I want to show a Map, for that I want to add `google-play-service-lib` but when I add it my `R.java` files gets deleted and not getting regenerated.

I tried adding `google-play-service-lib` into build path. After adding everything goes ok. But, when I run the project it gives an error says, `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable`

And when I add it into the project, `R.java` gets deleted. I tried number of permutations and combinations which I found on `google` and `SO`. But there is no feasible solution, which solves my problem.

Please help me out for this..!!

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<fragment
 android:id="@+id/map_gle"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you looked at the errors generated in "Problems"?

Comment: Ya, I tried everything. and also cleaned project 50 times.. still not working.. :(

Comment: what are the errors reported in Problems ?

Comment: When I import the google_library, it deleted the R.java and when I remove the library it shows error like missing com.google.gms......

Comment: Can you post the contents of your manifest?

Comment: @Arman::I can't.. due to security reasons.. Please tell me what u want check??

Comment: @mitesh you might have problems in some lines of your manifest. Just don't share parts of the manifest that needed to be private.